# 5 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-fs, rn-fetch-blob

I am using this library rn-fetch-blob https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob?activeTab

When I install the library and run the code its give me these errors:

> 5 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
> Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

At least I gie the solutions of common

Step 1: Go to TARGETS -> Build Settings -> No Common Blocks -> No

Step 2: Go to TARGETS -> Build Settings -> enable testability -> No
Also pod degenerate and pod update not working .